# push only unique elements in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array object(x) that stores json (key,value) objects. I need to make sure that x only takes json object with unique key. Below, example 'id' is the key, so i don't want to store other json objects with 'item1' key.

```
x = [{"id":"item1","val":"Items"},{"id":"item1","val":"Items"},{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}]    

var clickId = // could be "item1", "item2"....
var found = $.inArray(clickId, x);  //
if(found >=0)
{
    x.splice(found,1);
}
else{
    x.push(new Item(clickId, obj)); //push json object
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Javascript Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Use an object instead of an array, and make the `id` the property names. Then they're automatically unique.

Comment: Using an object compare would help here, take a look at _.lodash it's a very useful Javascript utility library with a method called _.isEqual that performs deep object compares.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

would this accomplish what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/gukv9arj/3/

```
x = [
    {"id":"item1","val":"Items"},
    {"id":"item1","val":"Items"},
    {"id":"item2","val":"Items"}
];    

var clickId = [];
var list = JSON.parse(x);
$.each(list, function(index, value){
    if(clickId.indexOf(value.id) === -1){
        clickId.push(value.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: goodmode:i would like to push an 'Item' object rather than just 'id'.

Comment: simple fix, just change to `clickId.push(value);`

Comment: working on getting a jsfiddle for you, if you'd like

Comment: Why use jsfiddle instead of [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)?

Comment: because I haven't taken the time to learn how to implement it yet, https://jsfiddle.net/gukv9arj/3/

Comment: @Barmar because jsfiddle is better

Comment: @goodmode thnks for jsfiddle. What do i need to do if i want to update item1 in case values are different.

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.parse(x)`? `x` is already an array of objects.

Comment: @smtp please see my answer for a more comprehensive solution

Comment: @godmode `clickId.push(value)` would break your logic when you attempt to do `clickId.indexOf(value.id)`

Comment: @canon only because OP said to expect JSON

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `inArray()` because you are searching for an `object`.

I'd recommend rewriting a custom find using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as follows.

```js
var x = [{"id":"item1","val":"Items"},{"id":"item1","val":"Items"},{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}]    

var clickId = "item1";
var found = x.some(function(value) {
  return value.id === clickId;
});
alert(found);
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. He's not searching for the element, he wants to remove duplicate IDs.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The way I read the question it seems like he has an array of objects and wants to determine if the array contains an object with a certain property in the `id`. You could be right too though.

Comment: He said **I need to make sure that x only takes json object with unique key.**

Comment: Thank you, @dave. It helped me. I just want to check the whether the data I want to push is already present or not.

Answer (score 1):

Almost 6 years later i ended up in this question, but i needed to fill a bit more complex array, with objects. So i needed to add something like this.

```
var values = [
  {value: "value1", selected: false},
  {value: "value2", selected: false}
  //there cannot be another object with value = "value1" within the collection.
]
```

So I was looking for the value data not to be repeated (in an object's array), rather than just the value in a string's array, as required in this question. This is not the first time i think in doing something like this in some JS code.

So i did the following:

```
let valueIndex = {};
let values = []
//I had the source data in some other and more complex array. 
for (const index in assetsArray) 
{
    const element = assetsArray[index];
    if (!valueIndex[element.value])
    {
        valueIndex[element.value] = true;
        values.push({
            value: element.value,
            selected: false
        });
    }
}
```

I just use another object as an index, so the properties in an object will never be repated. This code is quite easy to read and surely is compatible with any browser. Maybe someone comes with something better. You are welcome to share!
Hopes this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in pure javascript.

```js
var x = [{"id":"item1","val":"Items"},{"id":"item1","val":"Items"},{"id":"item1","val":"Items"}];

function unique(arr, comparator) {
  var uniqueArr = [];
  for (var i in arr) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j in uniqueArr) {
      if (comparator instanceof Function) {
        if (comparator.call(null, arr[i], uniqueArr[j])) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      } else {
        if (arr[i] == uniqueArr[j]) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      uniqueArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArr;
};

u = unique(x, function(a,b){ return a.id == b.id; });
console.log(u);

y = [ 1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,1];
console.log(unique(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

JS objects are great tools to use for tracking unique items.  If you start with an empty object, you can incrementally add keys/values. If the object already has a key for a given item, you can set it to some known value that is use used to indicate a non-unique item.

You could then loop over the object and push the unique items to an array.

```
var itemsObj = {};
var itemsList = [];
x = [{"id":"item1","val":"foo"},
    {"id":"item2","val":"bar"},
    {"id":"item1","val":"baz"},
    {"id":"item1","val":"bez"}];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var item = x[i];
    if (itemsObj[item.id]) {
        itemsObj[item.id] = "dupe";
    }
    else {
        itemsObj[item.id] = item;
    }
}

for (var myKey in itemsObj) {
    if (itemsObj[myKey] !== "dupe") {
        itemsList.push(itemsObj[myKey]);
    }
}

console.log(itemsList);
```

See a working example here: https://jsbin.com/qucuso

If you want a list of items that contain only the first instance of an id, you can do this:

```
var itemsObj = {};
var itemsList = [];
x = [{"id":"item1","val":"foo"},
    {"id":"item2","val":"bar"},
    {"id":"item1","val":"baz"},
    {"id":"item1","val":"bez"}];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var item = x[i];
    if (!itemsObj[item.id]) {
        itemsObj[item.id] = item;
        itemsList.push(item);
    }
}

console.log(itemsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late but I did something like the following:

```
let MyArray = [];
MyArray._PushAndRejectDuplicate = function(el) {
    if (this.indexOf(el) == -1) this.push(el)
    else return;
} 

MyArray._PushAndRejectDuplicate(1); // [1]
MyArray._PushAndRejectDuplicate(2); // [1,2]
MyArray._PushAndRejectDuplicate(1); // [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a very readable solution with lodash.

`x = _.unionBy(x, [new Item(clickId, obj)], 'id');`

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = [{id:item1,data:value},{id:item2,data:value},{id:item3,data:value}]
let newEle = {id:newItem,data:value}
let prev = x.filter(ele=>{if(ele.id!=new.id)return ele);
newArr = [...prev,newEle]
```