# How to create a new Data Structure from incoming JSON based on specific child Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an incoming Json list that looks like the below

```
[{
    "id": 190,
    "title": "This is a Story title",
    "category": [{
        "id": 43,
        "title": "XXX",
        "titleFr": "YYY"
    }, {
        "id": 27,
        "title": "AAA",
        "titleFr": "BBB"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 191,
    "title": "This is a Story title 2",
    "category": [{
        "id": 43,
        "title": "XXX",
        "titleFr": "YYY"
    }]
}]
```

I would like to be able to find all the Unique Category Ids, then create a new Data Structure (array) by Grouping  by the Category...ie

**Category 27- AAA**

This is a Story title

**Category 43 - XXX**

This is a Story title

This is a Story title 2

I have the below code, which I can use so far to traverse and get the Categories

```
$.each(data, function (i, ob) {
    $.each(ob, function (ind, obj) {
        if (ind === "category") {
            Categories.push(this);
        }
    });
});
console.log(Categories);
```

I feel like the above would be highly inefficient, plus it doesn't account for if the Category already exists.

Secondly, I think I would then need to go back over the entire list again, look for the Category.Id, create a new obj when found, then add to a new list?

I feel like there's a lot of looping here and using $.each would be very inefficient.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's completely clear what you need, but these solutions might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709845/push-only-unique-elements-in-an-array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780508/selecting-distinct-values-from-a-json/17781071

Comment: Maybe it would make it easier for you and others to play with this fiddle that I started using mostly your code from above.  http://jsfiddle.net/fqjpwt13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with vanilla JavaScript, building a list of categories using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on your input data, iterating over each of the categories for each story and pushing the story titles into an array in the category entry. You can then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to convert the result object into an array:

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 190,
  "title": "This is a Story title",
  "category": [{
    "id": 43,
    "title": "XXX",
    "titleFr": "YYY"
  }, {
    "id": 27,
    "title": "AAA",
    "titleFr": "BBB"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 191,
  "title": "This is a Story title 2",
  "category": [{
    "id": 43,
    "title": "XXX",
    "titleFr": "YYY"
  }]
}];

const categories = Object.values(data.reduce((cats, v) => {
  v.category.forEach(c => {
    cats[c.id] = cats[c.id] || {
      id : c.id,
      title : c.title,
      titleFr : c.titleFr,
      stories : []
    };
    cats[c.id].stories.push(v.title);
  });
  return cats;
}, {}));

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: Amazing, this does EXACTLY what I need.  I was expecting to spend the day hacking the data, thank you!

Comment: @TimCadieux cool - I wasn't sure if the output format would be right for your needs, so I'm glad to hear it was.